# OEM USB Drivers Lenovo

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-drivers, lenovo

What's the URL for Lenovo drivers?

I tried to run my first Android app on my Lenovo tablet (Android 4.2).
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

My OS is Windows 7. I tried to download the Lenovo driver here, but the URL is corrupted:
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers

Comment: have you downloaded the SDK already?

Comment: It's not asking for a recommendation, the question needs help finding the official driver.  Shouldn't have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

1. Download the Android SDK, and try the driver inside the SDK.
2. Check out this link: [Android Lenovo ADB Interface Driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds022366)

Comment: i find it here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/fn1ozc9174b71db/IdeaPadA3000_extended_Driver.rar

Comment: Where abouts in the Android SDK folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`) is the required driver?

Comment: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`